# Подключение к mssql с помощью фрэймворка express на node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

Пытаюсь понять как работать с mssql в связке с node.js express. Возник вопрос, не понимаю как быть.
При проверке соединения с помощью логина и пароля, передаю их в sql config и делаю так:

```
 const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect()
```

Тут все здорово, коннект есть, jwt токен получен и залогинился на сайт. А далее допустим мне надо сделать еще запрос с какой либо страницы. И вот тут мне не совсем понятно, нужно снова передавать логин и пароль в конфиг:

```
 config.user = req.body.login 
 config.password = req.body.password
```

чтобы создался пул, после чего делать запрос? Я кажется где-то не прав, потому как это явно неправильно, при каждом запросе передавать логин и пароль, где-то торможу, подскажите.

Comment: вам не нужно под каждый запрос клиента создавать коннект/пулл. вам нужно написать модуль, который будет сам создавать внутри себя пулл, делать коннект и из этого модуля экспортировать ваш "драйвер бд" (const pool). примерно как тут https://github.com/taihoinst01/cjlogisticsManager/blob/340f0ba21fe89cc5a9d9584cd259f9f465ee04dc/ExpressApp2/ExpressApp2/config/dbConnect.js#L64

Comment: на самом деле я от балды взял первую репу в коде которой нормальный подход. но лучше сразу приучаться к чему-то хорошему, так что посмотрите на существующие orm: https://typeorm.io/, https://sequelize.org/

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо за комментарий. А есть пример хоть какой-то? Просто не понимаю, как модуль внутри себя может создавать пул и делать коннект без логина и пароля пользователя, ведь надо передавать конфиг

Comment: пример по первой ссылке, я дал строчку с которой нужно читать

Comment: @nörbörnën, посмотрел пример, метод GetConnection там также пул создается через dbConfig, а в нем прописан логин и пароль ,без них в этом конфиге работать же не будет

Comment: да, ты один раз создал коннект и дальше всякий раз когда ты вызываешь getconnection тебе возвращают существующее соединение

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо, попробую)

Comment: можешь, для простоты понимания, сделать в своем модуле 2 функции: createConnection и getConnection, в первой только создавать, во второй только возвращать существующее. и createConnection вызывать один раз, в главном файле приложения (а внутри then callback-a вызывать app.listen)

Comment: получилось?____

Comment: @nörbörnën, да получилось, более менее, спасибо) Сделал в модуле метод Init где если пул не пустой возвращаю его иначе создаю подключение и возвращаю.

Comment: @nörbörnën, возник еще вопрос по твоей ссылке: в файлах роутинга вижу в блоке finally sql.close(), а это нормально?

Comment: не нужно так делать. тебе же пишут в документации: We also do not close the pool after the query is executed and that is because other queries may need to be run against this pool and closing it will add an overhead to running the query. We should only ever close the pool when our application is finished.

Comment: почитай документацию к модулю, там же шикарный раздел [Pool Management](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#pool-management)